# How can we skip Web config and app setting file simultaneously in VSTS build and release pipeline in ASP.Net project?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I am able to skip web.config but my app setting is not skipped when I run my release pipeline

[image]